# How to cleanup "react-beautiful-dnd" Draggable after removal?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using this awesome [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) library to let users reorder a list of items by "drag and drop". It works just fine. The only problem I've encountered is about when a user removes one of the items in the list. It seems that the "Draggable" component doesn't cleanup itself after getting unmounted:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);

<DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
    <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
        {(provided) => (
            <div
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Draggable
                          key={item.id}
                          draggableId={item.id.toString()}
                          index={index}
                        >
                            {(provided) => (
                                <div
                                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                                >
                                    <DraggableItem
                                      item={item}
                                      setItems={setItems}
                                    />
                                </div>
                          )}
                        </Draggable>
                    );
                })}
                {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
        )}
    </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```

As you can see, "setItems" is passed to "DraggableItem" component so that it can update state after removing an item.

It correctly updates state and everything is just fine but I get this "Warning" on my browsers console:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

How am I supposed to cleanup after updating items by calling "setItems"?